# DivideByZeroException being thrown as FatalExecutionEngineError, not caught

Tags: c#

My C# (.Net Framework 4.6.2) application was crashing with no logs. After some days of trial and error I found that the source seems to be a simple divide by zero bug. However, that section of code is in a try-catch, but instead of being thrown and caught, the debugger (Visual Studio 2019 v16.2.5) is showing an uncaught "FatalExecutionEngineError".

`Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0xf7bee845, on thread 0x760c. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.`

After continuing, this exception shows and then the application process dies.

`System.ExecutionEngineException: 'Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.`

This seems to happen even when no debugger is attached.

Very strange. Is there a way to catch this type of exception? What might be causing the DivideByZeroException to not be caught?

Here is the section of code:

```
{
...
///line that causes the exception when 'amount' is zero
int toScaleToWidth = (int)(bmp.Width / amount), toScaleToHeight = (int)(bmp.Height / amount);
...
}
catch(Exception ee)
{
//logging
}
```

Update. Some helpful comments by @gravity and @KlausGütter made me wonder if the issue would still happen if the bmp.Width variable was replaced with a fixed number. It does.

[image: Exception thrown on this line]

Comment: If the try .. catch isn't catching it, you might not have a suitable catch() statement for that exception. Alternatively, it may be that the exception is coming from outside that code. Can you provide some example code of where you think the exception is coming from?

Comment: Why do you think this is related to division by 0?
0xC0000005 is STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION. Does your application use unmanaged code (via COM Interop or P/Invoke)?

Comment: I added some code above. The exception only happens when 'amount' is zero. The try/catch is for all exceptions.

Comment: How/why would `amount` ever equal `0`?  Have you stepped backwards to determine that scenario and make a decision prior to entering in here?  I would defer to LordPupazz's comment - "... coming from outside that code?"  You're clearly trying to do some work here, that seems to be mandatory to continuing forth.  Why would `amount` be `0` then?

Comment: What is `bmp`? Are you sure that accessing its Height and Width properties works? I ask because this might involve some unmanaged code to run.

Comment: Re gravity's comment - I can fix the 'amount = 0' issue. My question is why wasn't this caught by the try catch? Is there some other larger issue at work?

Comment: Re @KlausGütter question. bmp.Width is just an int. There is some unmanaged code elsewhere but its not getting hit in these lines. Com or P/Invoke not used.

Comment: Did you try to collect stack trace or check event log for details?

Comment: The most likely cause for an engine error that happens only if a division by zero happens (assuming that is indeed what's happening!) is a bug in the JIT; as division by zero itself does cause an exception, but not this one. For example, something may have gone wrong setting up the exception handler blocks, or else code was optimized incorrectly and the exception location itself is a red herring. Try running the application as the opposite bitness (32-bit vs. 64-bit) and shifting the code around (for example, removing the exception handler, and splitting up the method).

Comment: In the end I suspect you'll find some other code is failing when `amount` is zero, not due to any division but (for example) a stray GDI call that doesn't validate its input neatly and overruns a buffer or dereferences a null pointer. Stack/heap corruption is another possibility. Pinning this down can be tricky; rearranging the code and making sure to run without optimization (debug mode) is your best bet. Turning on [managed debugging assistants](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/diagnosing-errors-with-managed-debugging-assistants) can also be helpful.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - can confirm it happens in both x64 and x86. I'll take a look at managed debugging assistants. Also seems to happen when there's no debugger at all (ie. released, deployed application on end user PC).

Comment: That's good, because it more or less proves that the problem is reproducible and not local (i.e. stray antivirus DLL injecting code, preview version of the JIT, bug in VS itself), so these things can be struck from the list as possible causes. That doesn't necessarily make solving it simpler, of course.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio the default settings suppress certain exceptions from breaking at the point they're thrown.

The way to catch ALL exceptions is to change this default setting in the Exceptions window in Visual Studio from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

This doesn't "always" help but it's a good start because the call stack is more immediate when you break on the line that is actually throwing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It didn't seem to make any difference. The exception was not caught and VS reported a FatalExecutionEngineError as before.